# Plugin creation for affiliate tracking

Tags: joomla-3.x

I am trying to figure out how difficult it would be to create a custom plugin that would identify an affiliate conversion.

I am using Joomla [Event Booking extension](https://www.joomdonation.com/joomla-extensions/events-booking-joomla-events-registration.html) and am looking at implementing Joomla Affiliate Tracker alongside it. Affiliate tracker has a [custom API](https://www.joomlathat.com/affiliate-tracker/custom-tracking-api) which can be used to track almost anything.

Events booking does have a default.php file for the booking completion page, the code of which is:

```
    <?php
/**
 * @package         Joomla
 * @subpackage      Event Booking
 * @author          Tuan Pham Ngoc
 * @copyright       Copyright (C) 2010 - 2018 Ossolution Team
 * @license         GNU/GPL, see LICENSE.php
 */
// no direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;
?>
<div id="eb-registration-complete-page" class="eb-container">
    <h1 class="eb-page-heading"><?php echo JText::_('EB_REGISTRATION_COMPLETE'); ?>
        <?php
        if ($this->showPrintButton === '1' &&  !$this->print)
        {
            $uri = JUri::getInstance();
            $uri->setVar('tmpl', 'component');
            $uri->setVar('print', '1');
        ?>
            <div id="pop-print" class="btn hidden-print">
                <a href="<?php echo $uri->toString(); ?>" target="_blank" title="<?php echo JText::_('EB_PRINT_THIS_PAGE'); ?>" rel="nofollow">
                    <span class="<?php echo $this->bootstrapHelper->getClassMapping('icon-print'); ?>"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </h1>
    <div id="eb-message" class="eb-message"><?php echo $this->message; ?></div>
</div>
<?php
    if ($this->print)
    {
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.print();
        </script>
    <?php
    }
    echo $this->conversionTrackingCode;
?>
```

I have done some minor customisation and overrides before, but was looking for some advice/guidance on whether this would be simple to create? They have quoted me 350EUR for the plugin, which I think is a bit steep. I will continue with my research but was hoping someone could advise whether It would be simple enough to implement something like this rather than pay them such a vast amount, as I'm pretty sure the client would not be willing to pay that.

Thank you in advance.

Regards
Donna

Answer (score 2):

I am not much familiar with the Event Bookings code as I didn't got a chance to work on it. For you I can suggest you to check if event booking have triggers in controller which can be called after successfully event booking sale. If it doesn't have such triggers then you will have to,  catch the variables on system Plugin events like onBeforeCompileHead to get request variables such as option, view and task etc depending on the variables set by it... Using them you get your work done for affilate conversion on condition of successful event booked.